# Howto encode special characters with haskell PDF EasyRender package?

Tags: haskell, pdf, character-encoding

I am using the Graphics.EasyRender haskell package to render PDF files.
Everything is fine with normal ascii characters, but I get encoding problems when using for example German Umlauts like öäüß or french chars like éè etc.

```
let document = newpage_defer $ do
  textbox align_left (Font Helvetica 12) (Color_Gray 0) 10 100 100 100 0 myStr

myStr :: String
myStr =  "test text ä"
```

the output is

```
test text ˆ⁄
```

I also tried to encode UTF8, but then it gets worse:

```
test text ˆ´⁄
```

As a test I also tries to generate postcript output from the EasyRender package, but there I have the same problems.

PDF is my main concern, any Idea how use these Umlauts in the target PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each PDF font has its own encoding, and usually PDF files has them embedded together with encoding information. `easyrender` doesn't embed fonts, it uses standard PDF fonts, that are deprecated.

AFAIU, `Helverica` uses the `StandardEncoding` (see PDF reference for details), and it doesn't contain `ä` character. So I don't think you can non-ASCII characters with `easyrender`.

To confirm, try to draw a string with byte (octal) `341` (and also `256` and `306` in case it uses `MacRomanEncoding` or `WinAnsiEncoding`), it should represent character `Æ`.

ADDED: Character `ä` in UTF8 is [represented](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e4/index.htm) as two bytes, `303` and `244`. In the `StandardEncoding` they represent `ˆ` and `⁄` -- exactly what you see in the first output. Not sure where `´` comes from in the second one.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. Re-encoding a standard font like Helvetica to be able to "show" characters in the range 128-255.
2. Representing characters 128-255 in a Postscript string.

The first is covered in Section 5.9.1 of the [Postscript Language Reference](https://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf), page 349. Another reference is http://apps.jcns.fz-juelich.de/doku/sc/ps-latin

The second is a deficiency with the easyrender library. One way to represent the character Ä (capital A with an umlaut) is via the octal
escape `\304`. That is, in the Postscript file you need to have:

```
(\304) show
```

However, looking at the library's source code, the function `ps_escape` is incapable of producing octal escape codes for characters in the range 128-255.

Another way to solve this problem is to emit the generated Postscript in the Latin1 encoding:

```
import System.IO
...

main = do
  let doc = newpage_defer $ do
    ...
  let output = render_string Format_PDF doc
  hSetEncoding stdout latin1
  putStr output
```

Putting these two ideas together:

```
import Graphics.EasyRender
import System.IO

reencode_fonts = " /Helvetica findfont dup length dict begin { 1 index /FID ne {def} {pop pop} ifelse } forall /Encoding ISOLatin1Encoding def currentdict end /Helvetica exch definefont pop"

my_custom = custom { ps_defs = reencode_fonts }

document = newpage_defer $ do
  textbox align_left (Font Helvetica 12) (Color_Gray 0) 10 100 100 100 0 myStr
  endpage 500 500

myStr :: String
myStr =  "test text ä"

out = render_custom_string Format_PS my_custom document

main = do
  hSetEncoding stdout latin1
  putStr out
```